# Self-closing tag in xml parsing using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml file to get news from rss feed. But self closing, empty tags are not parsed properly. Some of the items doesnt have a description tag.

My xml looks like this

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Tata Group</title>
    <link>http://www.tata.com</link>
    <description>
    Tata is a rapidly growing business group based in India with significant international operations. The business operations of the Tata Group currently encompass seven business sectors: communications and information technology, engineering, materials, services, energy, consumer products and chemicals.
    </description>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2014 Tata Sons Ltd</copyright>
    <item>
      <title>Tata Power commissions waste water recovery plant at power house #6, Jamshedpur
      </title>
      <link>
        http://www.tata.com/rssread.aspx?artid=tiEeXsbwZ54=
      </link>
      <description>Jamshedpur: Tata Power, India's largest integrated power company, has adopted several innovative technological solutions to improve the plant processes at its generation faciliti...
      </description>
      <pubDate>22 Jul 2014 12:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
    </channel>
    </rss>
```

Currently what I'm getting is, I could see all the items that has non-empty description tags and all the items with empty self closing description tags are skipped.

```
try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        FileReader xmlReader = new FileReader(destination);
        xpp.setInput(xmlReader);
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        String NodeValue;
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                NodeValue = xpp.getName();// Start of a Node
                if (NodeValue.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    flagItem = true;
                } else if (NodeValue.equalsIgnoreCase("title") && flagItem) {
                    eventType = xpp.next();
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                        message.setTitle(xpp.getText());
                    }
                } else if (NodeValue.equalsIgnoreCase("description/") && flagItem) {
                    message.setDescription("Description not available..");
                    Log.out(logFlag, logTag, "Reaching the critical point...........  self closing tag reached!!!");
                    flagItem = false;
                    list.add(message);
                    message = null;
                    message = new Message();

                } else if (NodeValue.equalsIgnoreCase("description") && flagItem) {
                    eventType = xpp.next();
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                        message.setDescription(xpp.getText());
                        flagItem = false;
                        list.add(message);
                        message = null;
                        message = new Message();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
            Log.out(logFlag, logTag, "xml file downloaded : "+list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
    // ...
    break;
```

For the general case, you may have to keep track of the "open" elements. But as you are only interested in `<description>`, you may be able to use a flag, set and cleared when you see a START_TAG. An empty element like `<description/>` is reported as a START_TAG followed by an END_TAG.

This is most certainly not correct, as the is definitely '/' not part of the local name:

```
NodeValue.equalsIgnoreCase("description/")
```

Omit the '/' from the string.

**Later** I noticed the `equalsIgnoreCase` method calls. You do know that XML is case sensitive w.r.t. element names?!